# Print `brew --cellar formula` with `--version`

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, zsh

I want to add some env. variable paths for `brew` formulas, e.g.

```
export MPI_HOME='/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.5'
```

but I don't want to hardcode version number, because if `brew` will upgrade formulas, I will need to change paths each time. I want to make `brew` print location in the cellar with formula version and then add to my `.zshrc` following line

```
export MPI_HOME=`brew --complete-cellar-path open-mpi`
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this,

```sh
export MPI_HOME=/usr/local/`ls -al $(which open-mpi) | cut -d '/' -f 6-8`
```

For example, if I want to grep the `PYENV_HOME`, I can do something like this,

```sh
$ ls -al $(which pyenv)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rchen  staff  32 Nov  1 16:59 /usr/local/bin/pyenv -> ../Cellar/pyenv/1.2.20/bin/pyenv

$ PYENV_HOME=/usr/local/`ls -al $(which pyenv) | cut -d '/' -f 6-8`

$ echo $PYENV_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.20
```

Answer (score 1):

This shell script handles edge caess well, such as atypical cellar locations, and getting the most-recent version. The script name is `brew-cellar-version`.

```bash
#/bin/sh
set -euf
formula="$1"
cellar=$(brew --cellar "$formula")
version=$(brew list --versions "$formula" | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
printf %s\\n "$cellar/$version"
```

Example:

```
% brew-cellar-version node
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.3.0
```

For your specific question, you would write:

```
export MPI_HOME=$(brew-cellar-version open-mpi)
```

Source: https://github.com/sixarm/brew-cellar-version